# Replacing a word in a text file with a value using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to replace a word in a text file with a value (say 1), but my outfile is blank.I am new to python (its only been a month since I have been learning it).

My file is relatively large, but I just want to replace a word with the value 1 for now.
Here is a segment of what the file looks like:

```
NAME SECOND_1

ATOM 1 6 0 0 0 # ORB 1

ATOM 2 2 0 12/24 0 # ORB 2

ATOM 3 2 12/24 0 0 # ORB 2

ATOM 4 2 0 0 4/24 # ORB 3

ATOM 5 2 0 0 20/24 # ORB 3

ATOM 6 2 0 0 8/24 # ORB 3

ATOM 7 2 0 0 16/24 # ORB 3

ATOM 8 6 0 0 12/24 # ORB 1

ATOM 9 2 12/24 0 12/24 # ORB 2

ATOM 10 2 0 12/24 12/24 # ORB 2

#1

#2

#3
```

I want to first replace the word ATOM with the value 1. Next I want to replace #ORB with a space. Here is what I am trying thus far.

```
input = open('SECOND_orbitsJ22.txt','r')
 output=open('SECOND_orbitsJ22_out.txt','w')
for line in input:
    word=line.split(',')
    if(word[0]=='ATOM'):
        word[0]='1'
        output.write(','.join(word))
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions or help? Thanks so much.

Comment: One thing you should make clear for better answers: do you want to replace _all_ occurrences of "ATOM" in your file (as suggested by your question text) or only those that appear at the beginning of the line (as suggested by your code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```
line.replace("ATOM", "1").replace("# ORB", " ")
```

Untested code:

```
input  = open('inp.txt', 'r')
output = open('out.txt', 'w')
clean  = input.read().replace("ATOM", "1").replace("# ORB", " ")
output.write(clean)
```

[Working example](http://codepad.org/C5rIuQIy).

Comment: Where would I put line.replace("ATOM","1") in the code I posted? Or would it be a different code? Sorry I am new to python.

Comment: input = open(file); output = input.read().replace("ATOM",1)  should replace all occurrances in file ... you dont need to evaluate each line

Comment: It didn't change anything in the outfile.

Comment: @JamdeJam, I can see it [working here](http://codepad.org/C5rIuQIy) (without reading from a file though)

Comment: @ Alexander..Thank you so much! It works great! Now I am going to try and create a comma delimted file with this..(Hopefully I can do this). Thanks again!

Comment: as an aside, I _think_ this code doesn't work very well for large text files. I'm working with a 250MB json file, and it just erases a bit of the end when I do this. Not sure if that's simply an error on my part or something more inherent in the command

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there's no comma after `ATOM` in the input, so `word[0]` doesn't equal `ATOM`. You should be splitting on spaces, not commas.

You could also just use `split()` without arguments.

Since you only do `output.write` when a match is found, the output stays empty.

P.S. Try to use `with` statements when opening files:

```
with open('SECOND_orbitsJ22.txt','r') as input,
    open('SECOND_orbitsJ22_out.txt','w') as output:
   ...
```

Also, Alexander suggests the right tool for replacement: `str.replace`. However, use it with caution as it's not position-aware. `re.sub` is a more flexible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the file segment you've pasted here, you'll want to split each line on a space, rather than a comma. If there are no commas, `line.split(',')` has no effect, and `word[0]` is empty. Your output file is empty because you are never writing to it, as `ATOM` will never be equal to the empty string.